# Proof associated with Laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\epsilon$ be a positive number and consider the function $f_\epsilon(x)$ defined by

$f_\epsilon(x)=\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ if $0\le x\le\epsilon$

$f_\epsilon(x)=0$ if $x>\epsilon$

For every $\epsilon>0$ we have $\int_0^\infty f_\epsilon(x)dx=1$

Show that

$L[f_\epsilon(x)]=\frac{1-e^{-p\epsilon}}{p\epsilon}$

and

$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} L[f_\epsilon(x)]=1$

I would appreciate help with this problem, as I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: Hint: you need to only compute $\int_{[0, \epsilon]} e^{-px} \ dx$.

Comment: @thisisme you need show how much you have done.

Answer (score 0):

$$L[f_\varepsilon (x)]=\int_{0}^{\varepsilon}\frac{e^{-pt}}{\varepsilon}dt+\int_{\varepsilon}^{\infty} 0dt=\int_{0}^{\varepsilon}\frac{e^{-pt}}{\varepsilon}dt=\frac{1-e^{-p\varepsilon}}{p\varepsilon}$$

$e^{-p\varepsilon}=1-p\varepsilon +p^2\varepsilon^2/2!-p^3\varepsilon^3/3!+\dots$

Then $$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\frac{1-e^{-p\varepsilon}}{p\varepsilon}=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}[1-p\varepsilon/2!+p^2\varepsilon^2/3!-\dots]=1$$